# Is there a way to tell what stored procedure called another stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am adding some debug code to a stored procedure that creates XML message. This stored procedure is called from many other stored procedures, and I want to see what stored procedures are calling that stored procedure that creates the XML.

Is there a system stored procedure that can provide this information?

For example, `SP1` calls `SP_XML`. IN `SP_XML`, add code to tell me that `SP1` is the caller.

Not sure if there is system stored procedure or a way to tell me this, even better would be if I can see the whole tree of stored procedure being called.

Answer (score 0):

hope this clarify you.

```
select schema_name(o.schema_id) + '.' + o.name as [procedure],
       'is used by' as ref,
       schema_name(ref_o.schema_id) + '.' + ref_o.name as [object],
       ref_o.type_desc as object_type
from sys.objects o
join sys.sql_expression_dependencies dep
     on o.object_id = dep.referenced_id
join sys.objects ref_o
     on dep.referencing_id = ref_o.object_id
where o.type in ('P', 'X')
      and schema_name(o.schema_id) = 'dbo'  -- put schema name here
      and o.name = 'help'  -- put procedure name here
order by [object];
```

Answer (score 0):

One piece of code I use to find a list of all stored procedures that reference is referenced is other procedures is:

```
WITH ProcsThatCallProcs (StoredProc, CodeID, calledproc) AS
(
    SELECT 
        Code = SCHEMA_NAME(Objects.schema_id) + '.' + Objects.name,
        CodeID = Objects.Object_id,
        called_proc = ISNULL((SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ReferencedOjbjects.name
                              FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies Referenced
                              INNER JOIN sys.objects ReferencedOjbjects ON Referenced.referencing_id = ReferencedOjbjects.object_id
                              WHERE Referenced.referenced_id = Objects.object_id
                              GROUP BY ReferencedOjbjects.name
                              ORDER BY ', ' + ReferencedOjbjects.name
                              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')), '')
    FROM sys.Objects Objects
    WHERE Objects.Type IN ('P', 'X')
)
SELECT 
    StoredProc,
    calledproc
FROM 
    ProcsThatCallProcs
WHERE 
    calledproc <> ''
ORDER BY 
    StoredProc
```

Comment: Sorry but my code is perfectly fine.  There is a better way of doing this but you cannot write that code with TSQL but you have to use the Microsoft SQL Server libraries.  Things you don't know anything about.